# unrecognized option '-EL'

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, android, clang

I'm trying to build an android kernel.
On every build I get a few errors:

- /usr/bin/as: unrecognized option '-EL'
  clang-16: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
- warning: field 'cgrp' with variable sized type 'struct cgroup' not at
  the end of a struct or class is a GNU extension
  [-Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end]
  struct group cgrp;
- warning: unused function 'dump_workqueue' [-Wunused-function]
  static void dump_workqueue(void) {}

Here are what I've tried so far

1. I tried different versions of clang, including [proton-clang](https://github.com/kdrag0n/proton-clang).
2. Tried different build methods, with and without a .sh script - basically followed the advice from YouTube build videos (here are some of them: [one](https://youtu.be/mOmKa89B8dg), [two](https://youtu.be/CV09EjAqQl8), [three](https://youtu.be/aIPlP26PoNY)).
3. Tried changing distribute linux.
4. Tried to change kernel build configuration.
5. At the end, I combined several options and results from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799641/usr-bin-as-unrecognized-option-el), but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

No more ideas and information on the Internet.
Please help me how to solve this.

I use clang-r475365b and gcc android-11.0.0_r48
My Kernel: https://github.com/OnePlusOSS/android_kernel_oneplus_sm8250/tree/oneplus/SM8250_R_11.0

My build.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ -d "out" ]]
then
    cd out && make clean && make distclean && make mrproper && cd ..
else
    mkdir -p out
fi

make O=out ARCH=arm64 vendor/bengal-perf_defconfig

PATH="${HOME}/heh/Desktop/clang/bin:${HOME}/heh/Desktop/toolchains/bin${PATH}" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${HOME}/heh/Desktop/clang/lib:${HOME}/heh/Desktop/toolchains/lib${PATH}" \

make                  O=out \
                      ARCH=arm64 \
                      SUBARCH=arm64 \
                      CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android- \
                      CROSS_COMPILER=$PATH \
                      CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- \
                      RANLIB=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-ranlib \
                      CC='/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/clang -fintegrated-as' \
                      AR=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-ar \
                      AS=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-as \
                      NM=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-nm \
                      OBJCOPY=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-objcopy \
                      OBJDUMP=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-objdump \
                      READELF=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-readelf \
                      OBJSIZE=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-size \
                      STRIP=/home/heh/Desktop/clang/bin/llvm-strip \
                      -j4
```

I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799641/usr-bin-as-unrecognized-option-el), but the solution presented there did not help